# SQL Input takes the first row content from the DB rather than the selected row content

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a PHP page to display the products in the DB table while displaying them if a user click on Add to cart or Add to wishlist the respective form submits and the product details get inserted into another table in DB,

While the insert works fine but the whatever the product user adds to cart only the first row in the table gets in inserted.

My code as goes:

**index :**

```
<?php 
        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM cakes ORDER BY date2 DESC LIMIT 30";
        $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
        if ($result3->num_rows > 0) { 
        while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) { 
?>
         <div class="bt-item-extra product-layout odd element-4">
          <section class="product-thumb bt-item transition">
     <div class="image">
<a href="individual.php?id=<?php echo $row3['id'];?>"><img src="images/product/<?php echo $row3['name'];?>.jpg" style="width:200px;" alt="Tasty Cakes" title="Tasty Cakes" class="img-responsive" />
 </a>
                   <div class="button-group button-grid">
                    <form action="addtocart.php" method="post" id="addtocart"></form>
                    <form action="addtowishlist.php" method="post" id="addtowishlist"></form>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $localIP; ?>" form="addtocart" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="cake" value="<?php echo $row3['name'];?>" form="addtocart" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row3['price'];?>" form="addtocart" />                          
                    <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $localIP; ?>" form="addtowishlist" />
                <input type="hidden" name="cake" value="<?php echo $row3['name'];?>" form="addtowishlist" />
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row3['price'];?>" form="addtowishlist" />

                <button class="btn-cart" type="submit" form="addtocart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>
               <button class="btn-wishlist" type="submit" form="addtowishlist" title="Add to Wish List"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
             </div>
              </div>
              <div class="small_detail">
                <div class="caption">
              <div class="name"><a href="individual.php?id=<?php echo $row3['id'];?>"><?php echo $row3['name'];?></a>
           </div>
           <p class="price">  ₹<?php echo $row3['price'];?>.00 </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div><!-- /.bt-item-extra -->

<?php     }
        } else {
     echo "";
}                                                  
?>
```

**Input.php**

```
<?php

$servername  = "localhost";
$dbusername = "uname";
$dbpassword = "pass";
$dbname = "dbname";

$cake = $_POST['cake'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$quantity= '1';

$ip = $_POST['ip'];

$date = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');
$date2 = date('M-d,Y');

$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO cart (cake, price, ip, quantity, date2)
VALUES ('$cake', '$price', '$ip', '$quantity', '$date2')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
header('Location: index.php');
}
else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

As i click on add to cart, the form submits and values get posted but only the first row content of the table is inserted instead of selected row content.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: `ORDER BY date2` maybe there have you problem

Answer (score -1):

I just figured out the answer.

since there are two forms in there and both of them are nested, i need to make the form id unique for each product.

so just echoed the ID of the product in front of form ID, as:

```
<?php 
        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM cakes ORDER BY date2 DESC LIMIT 30";
        $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
        if ($result3->num_rows > 0) { 
        while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) { 
?>
         <div class="bt-item-extra product-layout odd element-4">
          <section class="product-thumb bt-item transition">
     <div class="image">
<a href="individual.php?id=<?php echo $row3['id'];?>"><img src="images/product/<?php echo $row3['name'];?>.jpg" style="width:200px;" alt="Tasty Cakes" title="Tasty Cakes" class="img-responsive" />
 </a>
                   <div class="button-group button-grid">
                    <form action="addtocart.php" method="post" id="addtocart<?php echo $row3['id'];?>"></form>
                    <form action="addtowishlist.php" method="post" id="addtowishlist<?php echo $row3['id'];?>"></form>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $localIP; ?>" form="addtocart<?php echo $row3['id'];?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="cake" value="<?php echo $row3['name'];?>" form="addtocart<?php echo $row3['id'];?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row3['price'];?>" form="addtocart<?php echo $row3['id'];?>" />                          
                    <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $localIP; ?>" form="addtowishlist<?php echo $row3['id'];?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="cake" value="<?php echo $row3['name'];?>" form="addtowishlist<?php echo $row3['id'];?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row3['price'];?>" form="addtowishlist<?php echo $row3['id'];?>" />

                <button class="btn-cart" type="submit" form="addtocart<?php echo $row3['id'];?>"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>
               <button class="btn-wishlist" type="submit" form="addtowishlist**<?php echo $row3['id'];?>**" title="Add to Wish List"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
             </div>
              </div>
              <div class="small_detail">
                <div class="caption">
              <div class="name"><a href="individual.php?id=<?php echo $row3['id'];?>"><?php echo $row3['name'];?></a>
           </div>
           <p class="price">  ₹<?php echo $row3['price'];?>.00 </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div><!-- /.bt-item-extra -->

<?php     }
        } else {
     echo "";
}                                                  
?>
```

Hope this helps someone..